# Laravel 5.0 routes - POST URL with query string invoke controller defined for GET

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, laravel-5

I have 2 different controllers defined for GET and POST methods in the routes for the same URL, but when I use the paginator, it adds the query string to the end of the URL, I made the paginator links to make a AJAX POST on clicking, but it invokes the GET controller, below is the code in the Routes

```
Route::get('assets' , 'Assets\AssetController@index');
Route::post('assets', 'Assets\AssetController@searchResults');
```

this is the URL to which the AJAX POST request is made.

```
http://beta.rebuild.com/assets/?page=2
```

javascript code that does the AJAX POST

```
var url = $(obj).attr('data-page');
$('#assetsform').attr('action', url);
$('#assetsform').ajaxSubmit(function(response) {
        $('.results-table').append(response);
    }                   
);
```

Am I missing anything? please advise, I need the request to go to POST controller.

**Update:**
the problem occurs if I use a slash after the assets (assets/page) like this

```
http://beta.rebuild.com/assets/?page=2
```

but without the slash (assets?page=2) it make the POST properly, but the url rendered by laravel has the slash by default. is there a fix if I can make in the routes.php?

Answer (score 0):

You're Ajax request is to a url with GET parameter, also the default method for the method ajaxSumbit is GET and you're not telling the ajaxSumbit function you want to make a POST request so it makes a GET request instead.
You could try something like this:

```
var urlLink = $(obj).attr('data-page');
$('#assetsform').attr('action', urlLink);
var options = { 
    url:        urlLink,
    type: 'POST', 
    success:    function(responseText) { 
        $('.results-table').append(responseText); 
    } 
}; 
// pass options to ajaxForm 
$('#assetsform').ajaxForm(options);
```

Comment: the method in the form is already set to POST, I even tried to set the type as POST in the code, and it did not worked. I also check using the firebug and the request is POST for sure. on top of all this, I also removed all the AJAX related codes except this line "var url = $(obj).attr('data-page');"  to change and add the query string to the action attribute and then made a normal POST submit, even then it goes to the GET controller, the problem happens as soon as I add the ?page=2 to the action attribute, .. without adding it works good.